# primefaces component such as the tags input of stackoverflow

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, primefaces, components

I searched in the showcase of primefaces there a few days and I found one component such as the input of tags of this site (stackoverflow ;) )

but when I searched now I don't find it

do you know the component

if so, tell me please

Comment: You mean [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tagCloud.jsf)?

Comment: no, I mean one : when I do space the input text is remains alone

Comment: Do you want a component like "input of tags of stackoverflow" ?

Comment: What you describe seems to be an [autoComplete](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf) component. Try writing a letter into the first field of the form to see it working. If it isn't, can you please be a little more specific?.

Comment: Did you try:<p:inputText id="frequencies" /> <p:overlayPanel for="frequencies">..other component here...</p:overlayPanel>

Comment: if you mean p:overlaypanel then , it isn't

Comment: You can mix components to get the target you want, i think you can.

Comment: [autocomplete with multiple input](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteMultiple.jsf) is an input creating tags. Try typing "Messi" in the advanced one.

Comment: ok, thank you anyway RongNK

Comment: @simonTifo I'm posting it as an answer then. Still, that's not a question to ask here (google is there for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[autocomplete with multiple input is an input creating tags](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml). Try typing "Messi" in the advanced one.