# Primefaces tag similar to StackOverflow autocomplete tags?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932089/primefaces-component-such-as-the-tags-input-of-stackoverflow) which unfortunately doesn't solve my problem (even though it has an accepted answer, it seems that it's not answering the question)

Basically, i want to implement something like this with Primefaces 5.3:
[image: StackOverflow question's tags]
This is StackOverflow question's tags fragment. Is there something similar to this in Primefaces? I could not find any. I don't actually need suggested tags, i just need something like when you write a word, you press "*,*" (or *enter*, or something) and it takes the actual word as a value.

I don't know if i am being clear, i hope you get my point. Do you know something related to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I have done the following in primefaces. You have to hit "Enter" button after typing each word.

Today was a busy day. So could not improve location.reload yet

XHTML:

```
<p:autoComplete id="emailRecipients"
    value="#{scheduleDynamicReportCreateAction.selectedAuthUserNameAndEmails}"
    completeMethod="#{scheduleDynamicReportCreateAction.completeAuthUserNameAndEmails}"
    var="dto" forceSelection="false" queryEvent="enter" 
    itemLabel="#{scheduleDynamicReportCreateAction.fetShortVal(dto)}"
    itemValue="#{dto}" multiple="true" minQueryLength="1">

    <p:ajax event="query" listener="#{scheduleDynamicReportCreateAction.updateMe}" oncomplete="location.reload();"/>
    <p:column >  
     #{dto} 
    </p:column>
```

and in managedBean:

```
HashSet<String> returnList = new HashSet<String>();

public List<String> completeAuthUserNameAndEmails(String query) {
    returnList.add(query);
    updateMe();
    return null;
}

public void updateMe(){
    if(selectedAuthUserNameAndEmails == null){
        selectedAuthUserNameAndEmails = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    selectedAuthUserNameAndEmails.clear();
    selectedAuthUserNameAndEmails.addAll(returnList);
}


please implement itemUnSelect to remove items on x button


 <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{scheduleDynamicReportCreateAction.handleAuthUserNameAndEmailsSelect}" />
```

and remove items from selectedAuthUserNameAndEmails